# drawing histogram

Tags: java, image, jpeg, histogram

I want to draw a JPEG coefficient histogram

```
//coeff[] is the coefficients array
int hist[]=new int[25];
for(int i=0;i<coeff.length;i++)
hist[coeff[i]]++;
```

now I want To draw hist array like bar chart histogram ,but I don't know any function does that?
thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you didn't even _try_ Googling first.

Comment: I looked at JFreeChart but didn't know how to add the array as data set ?

Answer (score 5):

When you have a JFrame or something like this you can override the paint(Graphics g) method. Then you can draw the bars like this:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
  super.paint(g);
  final int barwidth = 20;
  for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
    g.fillRect(i*barwidth , 0, barwidth , hist[i]*10);
  }
}
```

Here is an example with a JLabel:

```
class Histogram extends JLabel{

//... make hist visible for this class

  @override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    final int BAR_WIDTH = 20;
    final int X_POSITION = 0;
    final int Y_POSITION = 200;
    for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
      g.fillRect(X_POSITION +i*BARWIDTH , Y_POSITION , BAR_WIDTH , -hist[i]*10);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can add it to your mainframe like this:

```
Histogram histogram = new Histogram();
add(histogram);
```

When this answer your question please mark the thread, thanks.

Comment: well, I want To show the histogram on a JLabel ,how could be that?

Comment: Then you must subclass from JLabel and override there the paint method.

Comment: Ah sorry there you must override the paintComponent method.

Comment: thanks riv333, but I've alot of Jlabels in the main frame of my application , how to specify for example Jlabel5 to show the histogram on it? thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your question correctly. But i think it is not a good idea to put a label (Histogram) in an existing label. Why not create an instance of the Histogram class and put these on your mainframe, that's all.

Comment: I want to show alot of things in the mainframe ,showing original image and its histogram and the modified image and its histogram,so I need to show the histogram in separated section so i used Jlabel ,but I don't know if I can use another component to show them in the same frame ,..... maybe there is a way to save the histogram as an image and then load it to the Jlabel ?

Comment: The histogram is from the type a JLabel. So you can add it like a JLabel to your mainframe. I edit my post.

Comment: thankX,I tried IT but there is an Error:  ("cannot override paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics) in javax.swing.JComponent attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was protected")

Comment: the error occurs because paintComponent() is a protected method, which cannot override with a public method. Try: protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)...

Comment: I edit it above. I also edit the fillRect function. The values must be negative if you not want that the histogramm is upside down.

Comment: thankX so much @riv33 ,I displayed it on separated JFrame ,the drawing started from the upper left corner ,and not very good appearance , I need to draw a professional histogram with all details about it , I read about JFreeChart library ,they said it provide a professional histograms to draw directly ,IF you know how to use it to draw Bar chart please tell me ,but If not I THANK you SO MUCH for your replays

Comment: Yes its more a histogram like the one in photoshop. When you want a complex histogram i think too, that a library is the easiest way. JFreeChart i don't know, but the first view looks good. It is LGPL.